# Is it possible to add an additional piece of logic to a "@hapi/joi" schema object?

Tags: node.js, express, joi

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

function validateInput(input)({
    const schema = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
        numApples: Joi.number().min(1).max(5).required(),
        numOranges: Joi.number().min(1).max(5).required()
    });

    return schema.validate(input);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is throw an error if the total apples and oranges doesn't equal 3 or more.
Is it possible to add custom logic this way using @hapi/joi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a new value `numApplesAndOranges` and set it equal to `numApples` + `numOranges` before including it in your schema.

You can now test like so: `numApplesAndOranges: Joi.number().min(3).required()`.

Full code would look like:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

function validateInput(input)({
     const numApplesAndOranges = input.numApples + input.numOranges;

     const schema = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
        numApples: Joi.number().min(1).max(5).required(),
        numOranges: Joi.number().min(1).max(5).required(),
        numApplesAndOranges: Joi.number().min(3).required()
    });

    return schema.validate({...input, numApplesAndOranges});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to below:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
function validateInput(input) {
    // custom validation function by hapi/joi
    const sum = function(fields = [], maxValue) {
        return function(value, helpers) {
            const sum = 0
            fields.forEach(f => {
                sum = sum + +input[f];
            });

            if (sum > maxValue) {
                return helpers.error('any.invalid');
            }
        }
    }

    const schema = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
        numApples: Joi.number().min(1).max(5).required(),
        numOranges: Joi.number().min(1).max(5).required().custom(sum(['numApples', 'numOranges'], 3))
    });

    return schema.validate(input);
```

You can learn more about custom validation in Joi [here](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#anycustommethod-description).

Hope this helps!